# how to stop infinite loop in react when click on the same tab again

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I am creating dashboard, in which there are 4 tabs on clicking tabs different panels are loaded and in that panel charts are loaded in my code there is `componentDidMount` as well as `componentDidUpdate` when I click on different tab proper functioning is there but when I click on the same tab it goes into infinite loop so how to avoid infinite loop when I click on the same tab twice.

```
class BarChartComponent extends React.Component 
{

   constructor(props) 
   {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
         data: null
      }
   };

   componentDidMount()
    {
            var that = this;
            $.ajax({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: "/querydata?query_id="+that.props.id,
                    success: function(data) 
                    {

                        console.log("component did mount method called");
                        console.log(1,JSON.stringify(data));
                        var BarChartData  = [
                        {
                            key: "totals",
                            values: []
                        }
                        ];
                        data['data'].forEach(function (d)
                        {
                            d.value= +d.value
                            BarChartData[0].values.push(d)
                        }) 
                        console.log(2,JSON.stringify(BarChartData))
                        that.setState({data:BarChartData});
                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    { 
                        console.error("Status: " + textStatus);
                        console.error("Error: " + errorThrown); 
                    }       
                });         
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)
    {

                    var that = this;
                    $.ajax({
                        method: "GET",
                        url: "/querydata?query_id="+that.props.id,
                        success: function(data) 
                        {

                            console.log("component did update method called");
                            var BarChartData  = [
                            {
                                key: "totals",
                                values: []
                            }
                            ];
                            data['data'].forEach(function (d)
                            {
                                d.value= +d.value
                                BarChartData[0].values.push(d)
                            }) 

                            if( _.isEqual(prevState.data , that.state.data ))
                            {
                                that.setState({data:BarChartData});

                            }                   
                        },
                        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
                        { 
                            console.error("Status: " + textStatus);
                            console.error("Error: " + errorThrown); 
                        }       
                    });         


    }



    render()
    {

        if (this.state.data==null)
        {
            return (<h1>Loading...</h1>);
        }
        return (


             <NVD3Chart type="discreteBarChart" datum={this.state.data} x="name" y="value" yAxis={{
             axisLabel:'Health Score'}} xAxis={{ axisLabel: 'Spines'}} />

        );
    }
}

window.BarChartComponent = BarChartComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you are updating state in the `componentDidUpdate` function. You're triggering another update when you do that, so it will call the `componentDidUpdate` function again and do it all over again. You need to add some type of check to the `componentDidUpdate` or `shouldComponentUpdate` function to prevent unnecessary updates. You can try to wrap the ajax call in an if statement: `if(prevState.data !== this.state.data)`.